# Calling variants with DeepVariant on targeted NGS sequencing (custom library)

Tags: ngs, variant-calling, deep-learning

I am seeking advice regarding DeepVariant analysis.

To avoid false positives I'm using several variant callers and then the resulting common set will be considered as TP variants.

One of the callers is [DeepVariant](https://github.com/google/deepvariant) (I'm using it by the first time). I used `DeepVariant-inception_v3-1.0.0+data-wes_standard` deep learning model (checkpoint) as a argument in `call_variants` function. However I don't have typical WES data (whole exome sequencing), but custom/target NGS pointed to plenty potential regulatory sequences i.e. promoters, TFBS and also pseudogenes and other non-coding stuff.

I have doubts whether my approach is correct, hence many variants may be discarded.

Should I use WGS (whole genome sequencing) model instead of WES model regarding training set preparation?

Or maybe this tool isn't a good choice regarding such custom experiment?

Best Regards, Adam